# Awk cannot parse profanity symbols

Tags: awk

The awk script

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = "\t"} $1==prev  {printf "\t" $2} $1 != prev {printf "\n" $1,$2} {prev=$1}'
```

falls over when it encounters a line with profanity. The lines below are tab separated after they year (in brackets).

```
Richard Pryor... Here and Now (1983)    stand-up  
Richard Pryor... Here and Now (1983)    stand-up-comedian  
Richard Pryor... Here and Now (1983)    stand-up-comedy  
Richard Pryor: I Ain't Dead Yet, #*%$#@!! (2003)    african-american
```

Error obtained

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=temp.list FNR=4) fatal: arg count with `$' must be > 0
```

Another line (again containing profanity that doesn't parse)

```
Merry F#%$in' Christmas (2005)  censored-profanity-in-title
```

Again the tab is after the year in brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `printf` errors account for the problem you see: `printf` needs a comma after the format specifier:

```
{printf "\t%s", $2} 
{printf "\n%s\t%s", $1,$2}
```

The way you're using it, you're concatenating a newline and $1 to form the format specifier. Since $1 contains an unesacaped `%`, printf gets confused and throws the error.

Additionally, your last line will not end with a newline, so add this clause at the end:

```
END {print ""}
```

Answer (score 2):

[@glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) is correct that `printf` is the cause of your syntactical problems.

A elegant approach is to use an associative array to build up the strings, this avoids the fiddly edge cases:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{a[$1]=a[$1] (a[$1]?FS $2:$0)} END{for (k in a) print a[k]}' file
```

Comment: An elegant solution. The ordering of the output will be random-ish. With GNU awk, you can use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"` to sort by the index value (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal)

Comment: Good tip @glennjackman my underlying assumption is the file is sorted lexicographically already so you could just throw it through sort after the awk to get the same ordering. Another benefit of this approach is the file doesn't need to be sorted for it work.

Comment: The file I am dealing with is 250MB. I wouldn't  want to create an array that size.